# How did the Justice League survive on the Anti-matter Earth in "JLA: Earth 2" if they're made of ordinary matter?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, justice-league

[image]!

In the Graphic Novel JLA: Earth 2, the Justice League travelled  to the Post-crisis Earth 2, which is presumably the Anti-matter universe of Qward without being annihilated, could someone please provide me a canonical explanation for how this was possible? There seems to be not enough discussion about this as well as how the anti-matter wave released by the Anti-Monitor during "Crisis on Infinite Earths" could destroy a planet so slowly, (compared to real life). Weren't the gamma rays by themselves able to wipe out the planets at the speed of light, in contrast to giving some heroes enough time to run away?

Comment: *bright flash* and *the end* would make quite a short and horrible comic book, don't you think?

Comment: My copy of that story is in a storage unit, and I don't remember what (if anything) writer Grant Morrison said about the details of the universe-hopping in the script. But I can tell you from memory that way back in the 1960s it was established in DC's comic books that there was a parallel antimatter universe, and people could hop back and forth between the two, via some sort of technology that automatically changed the regular matter in their bodies into antimatter, or vice versa, as required. Morrison may have assumed his readers in the 1990s would know he was respecting that tradition.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the anti-matter universe of Qward, which is a Green Lantern staple, with the dimension of Earth-2 (sometimes Earth-3) where the majority of people on Earth are evil-minded, Superman is Ultraman, Wonder Woman is Superwoman, Batman is Owlman, etc.  Earth-2 is featured in JLA/Justice League comics.

[image: 1980s Weaponers of Qward]

[image: modern Qward]

The antimatter universe of Qward is where Sinestro was exiled to after he was stripped of his Green Lantern power ring and status by the Guardians of the Universe.  Qward is populated by the evil Weaponers and Thunderers, who have had a rather constant history since being introduced.  The Weaponers are the ones who created yellow power rings for Sinestro, later recotnned into being prototype Fear emotion power rings.  Going back and forth from "our" universe to the Qward anti-matter universe always required the person(s) to use their power rings (or other methods) to change their atoms to anti-matter atoms and back again.

Earth-2 of JLA, however, has been done again and again, from from "opposites" of Superman, Batman, and Wonder Woman, to include an "opposite" of Green Lantern, the Flash, Aquaman, etc.

[image: Mirror JLA]

Recently, this "mirror JLA" took over our Earth, but the supervillians were slightly different, actually using the names Clark Kent, Lois Lane, Bruce Wayne, Hal Jordan, etc.  Ultraman's powers were not only from anti-Kryptonite, but he had to avoid direct sunlight, as well.  This was the "Forever Evil" blockbuster.

[image: Forever Evil]

So the antimatter universe of Qward is different from the Earth-2 of "villainous" humans.